# Actualizar un gridview

Tags: c#

Tengo un gridview el cual le cargo datos desde mi base de datos pero al actualizar me marca un problema, no toma los datos que quiero actuializar ¿Como puedo hacer que actualice o donde tengo el error?
esta es la accion de actualizar
protected void GridView5_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            Problema pr = new Problema();

```
        pr.idProblema = Convert.ToInt32(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex+1].Cells[2].Text);
        pr.N = GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Text;
        pr.D = GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Text;
        pr.S = GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Text;
        pr.E = Convert.ToBoolean(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Text);
        pr.i = Convert.ToInt32(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Text);
        pr.NumeroColumnas = Convert.ToInt32(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Text);
        pr.C= GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Text;
        if(AccessProblema.getActualizar(pr) == true)
        {

        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto, no es text si no Value porque es el valor que tiene esa celda que quieres

```
pr.idProblema = Convert.ToInt32(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex+1].Cells[2].Value);
pr.N = GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value;
pr.D = GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value;
pr.S = GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value;
pr.E = Convert.ToBoolean(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[6].Value);
pr.i = Convert.ToInt32(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[7].Value);
pr.NumeroColumnas = Convert.ToInt32(GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[8].Value);
pr.C= GridView5.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[9].Value;
```

Comment: Al probarlo de esa manera me marca un error que dice "que se cuenta con una definición para Value y no existe un metodo Value"

Comment: ¿Pero lo que quieres es obtener los valores de un datagridview?

Comment: y también quieres cargar los valores a un textbox eso es lo que quieres

Comment: ya tengo cargado los datos en gridview, quiero actualizar los datos de un renglón pero al la hora de actualizar no toma los valores de las cajas de texto que aparecen al actualizar y la pagina deja de funcionar y me envía un error de que los datos que toma están vacíos.

Comment: Pero lo que te estoy indicando es lo siguiente si quieres cagar los datos a los textbox y luego que estén cargados actualizarlos, eso es lo que digo porque de  otra forma no te estoy entendiendo

Comment: mas bien quiero guardar los datos de los textbox que el gridview habilitar  para editar  y despues actualizarlos

Comment: asi tengo el gridview <asp:GridView ID="GridView5" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="400px" ForeColor="#333333" OnRowDeleting="GridView5_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView5_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView5_RowUpdating" CellPadding="4" GridLines="None" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView5_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:GridView>

Comment: Te Recomiendo que edites la Pregunta para entender mejor